# how to sort a table in alphabetical order with antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want to filter the column in alphabetical order
here is the code to filter by the size
how to do
thank you

```js
const columns = [{
      title: 'First Name',
      dataIndex: 'first_name',
      sortDirections: ['descend', 'ascend'],
      key: 'first_name',
      width: '20%',
      sorter: (a, b) => a.first_name.length - b.first_name.length,

    }]
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can use `localeCompare()`

```
sorter: (a, b) => a.first_name.localeCompare(b.first_name);
```

Comment: This question is marked as duplicate but the linked question is for javascript and not for **antd**. This answer worked for me. :)

Comment: Its worked for me

Comment: I'ts true, the question is about antd design tables, this is what I was wanted, and worked for me.

Comment: The solution worked very well for me! :)

Comment: Worked great for me. However, AntD sort breaks when a field's value is null